# How to override properties of a CSS class altering the original value (less + mixin)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

Let's say I use bootstrap and what to override the `padding-top` of `jumbotron` class of a percentage using less and mixin

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
// this is my style.less file loaded *after* bootstrap.css
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: _original_padding-top_ * 0.5
}
```

Comment: It would be really nice to be able to `+=` or `-=` (or whatever) on a property's original value, but it's not possible. However, as you're using LESS, it's not unlikely that the original value is stored in a variable in which case you can use that like; `padding-top: $padding-top-variable * .5`

Comment: if so, this is the right answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/jumbotron.less

So you simply do something like:

```
@import "bootstrap/variables.less";

.jumbotron {
    padding-top: @jumbotron-padding * .5;
}
```

}

Comment: So I have to import the whole bootstrap dev package, for doing something like this, don't I? Is this true in general? I mean: what about if I wish to change a value not set by a variable? Is there a general rule for taking the original value of a property of a class and modify it?

Comment: @GianpieroCaretti The code above says: `@import "bootstrap/variables.less";`. Where do you see "the whole bootstrap package"?

Comment: *What about if I wish to change a value not set by a variable* - then it's simply not supposed to be modified (by authors design) and you're on your own with plain CSS overriding. There's no "general rule" - it is what it is - an old open source project designed through years by stacking kludges on top of each other - something has some concept behind, something hasn't.

Comment: in my project I only have the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js. I don't have the less files. From the answer above I understood I have to import all files distributed with bootstrap, in order to import ``bootstrap/variables.less``. Am I right?

Comment: Well, no, you'll need the only file you can download [right there](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/v3.3.7/less/variables.less).

Answer (score 0):

The `percentage` mixin only accepts one parameter, so what you propose is not possible.

See [here](http://lesscss.org/functions/#math-functions-percentage). It's always good to check the reference documentation.

You will have to create your own mixin to do that.